# Transform back modified image data from Firebird DB

Tags: javascript, image, delphi, blob, firebird

I have a program which is able to save images to a Firebird database, and also display them. I read data (my code is written in JavaScript) directly from database and work with it. The problem is that image data, stored in DB, is somehow modified (encoded, compressed, or whatever), and the buffer is bigger then original image buffer.

Now, I know for sure that my JavaScript code is working correctly (if I store image directly to the database, and then read it, I can create an image file).

What are the changes that the program does to the images, and how can I read it properly from the database with JavaScript? The program is written in Delphi, and looks like *JEDI Code Library v 2.2* is being used. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with these technologies.

This is the code I found, which works with images.

[image]

```
unit FIBPlusUCLStreams;

interface

procedure PackBuffer(var Buffer: PChar; var BufSize: LongInt);
procedure UnpackBuffer(var Buffer: PChar; var BufSize: LongInt);

implementation

uses
 DIUclStreams, Classes;

procedure PackBuffer(var Buffer: PChar; var BufSize: LongInt);
var srcStream, dstStream: TStream;
begin
  srcStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  dstStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    srcStream.WriteBuffer(Buffer^, BufSize);
    srcStream.Position := 0;
    UclCompressStream(srcStream, dstStream);
    srcStream.Free;
    srcStream := nil;
    BufSize := dstStream.Size;
    dstStream.Position := 0;
    ReallocMem(Buffer, BufSize);
    dstStream.ReadBuffer(Buffer^, BufSize);
  finally
    if Assigned(srcStream) then srcStream.Free;
    dstStream.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure UnpackBuffer(var Buffer: PChar; var BufSize: LongInt);
var srcStream,dstStream: TStream;
begin
  srcStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  dstStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    srcStream.WriteBuffer(Buffer^, BufSize);
    srcStream.Position := 0;
    UclDeCompressStream(srcStream, dstStream);
    srcStream.Free;
    srcStream:=nil;
    BufSize := dstStream.Size;
    dstStream.Position := 0;
    ReallocMem(Buffer, BufSize);
    dstStream.ReadBuffer(Buffer^, BufSize);
  finally
    if assigned(srcStream) then srcStream.Free;
    dstStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

```
function UclCompressStream(
  const AInStream: {$IFDEF KOL}PStream{$ELSE}TStream{$ENDIF};
  const AOutStream: {$IFDEF KOL}PStream{$ELSE}TStream{$ENDIF};
  const ACompressionLevel: Integer = 10;
  const ABufferSize: Cardinal = $1000;
  const AOnProgress: TUclProgress = nil;
  const AUser: Pointer = nil): Boolean;

function UclDeCompressStream(const AInStream, AOutStream: {$IFDEF KOL}PStream{$ELSE}TStream{$ENDIF}; const ABufferSize: Cardinal = $1000; const AOnProgress: TUclProgress = nil; const AUser: Pointer = nil): Boolean;
```

From library:

```
function UclDeCompressStream(const AInStream, AOutStream: {$IFDEF KOL}PStream{$ELSE}TStream{$ENDIF}; const ABufferSize: Cardinal = $1000; const AOnProgress: TUclProgress = nil; const AUser: Pointer = nil): Boolean;
label
  Fail;
var
  b, s: ^Byte;
  a, f, r, InBytes, OutBytes: Cardinal;
begin
  a := ucl_output_block_size(ABufferSize);
  InBytes := 0;
  OutBytes := 0;
  GetMem(b, a);
  try
    repeat
      f := AInStream.Read(r, SizeOf(r));
      Result := f = 0;
      if Result then Break;
      Result := f = SizeOf(r);
      if not Result then Break;
      Result := r <= a;
      if not Result then Break;
      s := b;
      Inc(s, a - r);
      Result := Cardinal(AInStream.Read(s^, r)) = r;
      if not Result then Break;
      f := a;
      {$IFDEF KOL}
      Result := ucl_nrv2e_decompress_asm_safe_8(s, r, b, f, nil) = UCL_E_OK;
      {$ELSE}
      Result := ucl_nrv2e_decompress_asm_fast_safe_8(s, r, b, f, nil) = UCL_E_OK;
      {$ENDIF}
      if not Result then Break;
      Result := Cardinal(AOutStream.Write(b^, f)) = f;
      if not Result then Break;
      if Assigned(AOnProgress) then
        begin
          Inc(InBytes, r);
          Inc(OutBytes, f);
          AOnProgress(InBytes, OutBytes, AUser);
        end;
    until False;
  finally
    FreeMem(b);
  end;
end;
```

And by message `EPNGZLIBErrorText = 'Could not decompress the image because it contains ' + 'invalid compressed data.'#13#10 + 'Description: ';` I have found this function:

```
{Reads from ZLIB}
function TChunkIDAT.IDATZlibRead(var ZLIBStream: TZStreamRec2;
  Buffer: Pointer; Count: Integer; var EndPos: Integer;
  var crcfile: Cardinal): Integer;
var
  ProcResult : Integer;
  IDATHeader : Array[0..3] of char;
  IDATCRC    : Cardinal;
begin
  {Uses internal record pointed by ZLIBStream to gather information}
  with ZLIBStream, ZLIBStream.zlib do
  begin
    {Set the buffer the zlib will read into}
    next_out := Buffer;
    avail_out := Count;

    {Decode until it reach the Count variable}
    while avail_out > 0 do
    begin
      {In case it needs more data and it's in the end of a IDAT chunk,}
      {it means that there are more IDAT chunks}
      if (fStream.Position = EndPos) and (avail_out > 0) and
        (avail_in = 0) then
      begin
        {End this chunk by reading and testing the crc value}
        fStream.Read(IDATCRC, 4);

        {$IFDEF CheckCRC}
          if crcfile xor $ffffffff <> Cardinal(ByteSwap(IDATCRC)) then
          begin
            Result := -1;
            Owner.RaiseError(EPNGInvalidCRC, EPNGInvalidCRCText);
            exit;
          end;
        {$ENDIF}

        {Start reading the next chunk}
        fStream.Read(EndPos, 4);        {Reads next chunk size}
        fStream.Read(IDATHeader[0], 4); {Next chunk header}
        {It must be a IDAT chunk since image data is required and PNG}
        {specification says that multiple IDAT chunks must be consecutive}
        if IDATHeader <> 'IDAT' then
        begin
          Owner.RaiseError(EPNGMissingMultipleIDAT, EPNGMissingMultipleIDATText);
          result := -1;
          exit;
        end;

        {Calculate chunk name part of the crc}
        {$IFDEF CheckCRC}
          crcfile := update_crc($ffffffff, @IDATHeader[0], 4);
        {$ENDIF}
        EndPos := fStream.Position + ByteSwap(EndPos);
      end;


      {In case it needs compressed data to read from}
      if avail_in = 0 then
      begin
        {In case it's trying to read more than it is avaliable}
        if fStream.Position + ZLIBAllocate > EndPos then
          avail_in := fStream.Read(Data^, EndPos - fStream.Position)
         else
          avail_in := fStream.Read(Data^, ZLIBAllocate);
        {Update crc}
        {$IFDEF CheckCRC}
          crcfile := update_crc(crcfile, Data, avail_in);
        {$ENDIF}

        {In case there is no more compressed data to read from}
        if avail_in = 0 then
        begin
          Result := Count - avail_out;
          Exit;
        end;

        {Set next buffer to read and record current position}
        next_in := Data;

      end {if avail_in = 0};

      ProcResult := inflate(zlib, 0);

      {In case the result was not sucessfull}
      if (ProcResult < 0) then
      begin
        Result := -1;
        Owner.RaiseError(EPNGZLIBError,
          EPNGZLIBErrorText + zliberrors[procresult]);
        exit;
      end;

    end {while avail_out > 0};

  end {with};

  {If everything gone ok, it returns the count bytes}
  Result := Count;
end;
```

Comment: This is unanswerable in its current state, as the code doesn't show any information about it is encoded or decoded. The `SaveToStream` code would probably give some hint about how it is encoded, as that seems to convert the data as stored in the DB to a TMemoryStream that is use to create the bitmap (which I guess/hope expects a normal binary stream).

Comment: This is quite... strange code, but it performs no encoding or conversion. Images are stored in BLOBs as is and their format is kinda auto-detected on load by signature. I would blame JS code.

Comment: I provided a screen with same image. On the right - actual image, which was inserted directly in database. My JavaScript code can easily read it and work with it. And image is displaying if press "As Picture". But on the left side - same picture, saved by program, and data is different.

Comment: Can you show the Delphi code that stores the image to the DB?

Comment: @BlurrySterk I added another piece of code, but I'm not sure if it's what's needed

Comment: @yurii I will not go through your code since this needs a database to test, but you can use Delphi to load the saved image from database. If you got the same image you saved from Delphi then you need to review your JavaScript code else you need to review your Delphi code. If your Delphi code is OK then post your JavaScript code.

Comment: It is some sort of compression: see how 3x `01`, 2x `00 48`, and 50x `3B` from the original only appear once on the left side.

Comment: It looks like FIB+ feature - "transparent packing of BLOB fields". Check FIB+ documentation for the description and if it is really used in the code.

Comment: @user13964273 yes, looks like FIB+ is being used. I changed the code. "UclDeCompressStream" -  is that what I am looking for?

Comment: It's usage was clear from the component's name. I never used FIB+ and has no documentation for it so I have no idea where to look at. That's why I said "check documentation" which you should have if you bought FIB+ license.